# How do I compare attributes of an object in an ArrayList against Scanner input?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have a simple 'Supplier/Product' Java application running in the Eclipse console.

Each 'Supplier' object has an ArrayList of 'Product' objects.

```
public class Supplier {

private int supCode;
private String supName;
private Address supAddress;
private SupRegion supRegion;
private ArrayList<Product> supProducts;

public Supplier(int supCode, String supName, Address supAddress, SupRegion supRegion,
        ArrayList<Product> supProducts) {
    super();
    this.supCode = supCode;
    this.supName = supName;
    this.supAddress = supAddress;
    this.supRegion = supRegion;
    this.supProducts = supProducts;
}
```

I then have another ArrayList containing the Supplier objects "supDatabase"

There are only 2 suppliers present at runtime created below:

```
//Suppliers
Supplier hendys = new Supplier(101, "Hendersons" , add1, SupRegion.UNITED_KINGDOM, hendysPros); 
Supplier palasFoods = new Supplier(102, "Palas Foods", add2, SupRegion.UNITED_KINGDOM, palasPros);


ArrayList<Supplier> supDatabase = new ArrayList<Supplier>();

//method to add all products into ProductArrayList
//also to add all suppliers to SupplierArrayList
public ArrayList<Supplier> populateDatabase(ArrayList<Supplier> supDB) {

    hendysPros.add(remote);
    hendysPros.add(remote1);
    hendysPros.add(remote2);
    hendysPros.add(remote3);

    supDatabase.add(hendys);

    palasPros.add(strawberries);
    palasPros.add(raspberries);
    palasPros.add(blueberries);

    supDatabase.add(palasFoods);


    return supDatabase;
}
```

I am now trying to add functionality to **add a new product to a specific supplier.**

The following method attempts to compare user's input of a Supplier 'code' with the data in the ArrayList (supDatabase):

```
private static void addNewProduct(Scanner sc)
{       
    System.out.println("Enter supplier code you would like to add a product to: ");
    int choice = getUserInput(sc);

    //***PROBLEM*** - trying to validate whether the user has entered an existing Supplier code i.e.
    //does the integer entered match a Suppliers's code, contained within a Supplier object
    //which are then contained within an ArrayList (supDatabase)


    for (int i=0; i<supDB.supDatabase.size();i++)           //for loop to cycle through ArrayList of Supplier objects??
    {
        if (choice == supDB.supDatabase.get(i).getSupCode())
        {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to add a product to: " + supDB.supDatabase.get(i).getSupName());

            Product newProduct  = new Product(0, "", "", 0, 0, false);

            System.out.println("Enter a code for the new product: ");
            newProduct.setProCode(sc.nextInt());

            System.out.println("Enter make: ");
            newProduct.setProMake(sc.next());

            System.out.println("Enter model: ");
            newProduct.setProModel(sc.next());

            System.out.println("Enter price: ");
            newProduct.setProPrice(sc.nextDouble());

            System.out.println("Enter the quantity available: ");
            newProduct.setProQtyAvailable(sc.nextInt());

            System.out.println("Is the product available? (Y/N)");
            newProduct.setProDiscontinued(sc.hasNext());                    

            //add the new created Product to the database ArrayList
            supDB.supDatabase.get(i).getSupProducts().add(newProduct);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Supplier code not present. Try again");
        }
    }

}
```

The comparison is only working for the first Supplier in the ArrayList and is not recognizing anything past it. I know this has something to do with the structure of addNewProduct().

**Can anyone recommend any restructuring or indeed any other techniques I could adopt for this?** (I realise the code i'm using at the minute is very basic so I am open to any new features I could bring in to tidy things up!)

Comment: Few initial thoughts...Will add more as I read the whole thing..public ArrayList<Supplier> populateDatabase(ArrayList<Supplier> supDB)..what is the subDB used for? It is not mentioned in the method. addNewProduct(Scanner sc): It would print the error message for every supplier that doesn't match. Doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use HashMap to store and look up suppliers instead of the ArrayList. Here is how the function would be different.

```
Map<Integer, Supplier> supDatabase = new HashMap<Integer, Supplier>();

//method to add all products into ProductArrayList
//also to add all suppliers to SupplierArrayList
public Map<Integer, Supplier> populateDatabase() {
    hendys.add(prod1);
    hendys.add(prod2);
    hendys.add(prod3);
    hendys.add(prod4);

    supDatabase.put(hendys.getSupCode(), hendys);

    palasFoods.add(strawberries);
    palasFoods.add(raspberries);
    palasFoods.add(blueberries);

    supDatabase.add(palasFoods.getSupCode(), palasFoods);


    return supDatabase;
}
```

This is assuming you have getters defined for supplier code in the Supplier object.

This would make the addNewProduct look as below:

```
private static void addNewProduct(Scanner sc)
{       
    System.out.println("Enter supplier code you would like to add a product to: ");
    int choice = getUserInput(sc);

    Map<Integer, Supplier> supDatabase = new HashMap<Integer, Supplier>();

    if (supDatabase.containsKey(sc)) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen to add a product to: " + supDB.supDatabase.get(i).getSupName());

        Product newProduct  = new Product(0, "", "", 0, 0, false);

        System.out.println("Enter a code for the new product: ");
        newProduct.setProCode(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Enter make: ");
        newProduct.setProMake(sc.next());

        System.out.println("Enter model: ");
        newProduct.setProModel(sc.next());

        System.out.println("Enter price: ");
        newProduct.setProPrice(sc.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Enter the quantity available: ");
        newProduct.setProQtyAvailable(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Is the product available? (Y/N)");
        newProduct.setProDiscontinued(sc.hasNext());                    

        //add the new created Product to the database ArrayList
        supDatabase.get(sc).getSupProducts().add(newProduct);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Supplier code not present. Try again");
    }
}
```

In case of an error, if you want the user to try again, you might need to put it in a loop so it asks the user again for input. Might be a good idea to put a counter on it or an exit loop if there are no suppliers or the user wants to exit.